# merge two matrices by column names

Tags: r, merge

i have

```
mat1 <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6), ncol=2)
colnames(mat1) <- c("Soa","Nor")
mat2 <- matrix(c(1,0,1,1,0), nrow=1)
colnames(mat2) <- c("reman","jak","Soa","Alein","Nor")
```

I need to get this matrices

```
Soa    Nor
1       4
2       5
3       6
1       0
```

I use this but does not work for column

```
merge(mat1,mat2, by="row.names", all = TRUE)
```

Comment: What is the logic behind this? What algorithm should we follow to get the result?

Comment: `mat1` is a 3x2 matrix, `mat2` is a 1x5 matrix, and you want a 4x2 matrix where the column names are numbers 3 and 5 from `mat2`.  None of these numbers make any sense together.

Comment: Try `rbind(mat1,mat2[,intersect(colnames(mat2), colnames(mat1))])`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is much more simple with `rbind`.  You can extract the relevant columns of `mat2` with `colnames(mat1)` and then bind them together.

```
> rbind(mat1, mat2[, colnames(mat1)])
#     Soa Nor
#[1,]   1   4
#[2,]   2   5
#[3,]   3   6
#[4,]   1   0
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick with `merge`, you could try this:

```
samecols <- intersect(colnames(mat1),colnames(mat2))
merge(mat1,mat2, by=samecols, all=TRUE)[samecols]
```

The difference to your code is, that `by` is a vector of column names here that both matrices share. As @akrun pointed out in his comment, the same thing can be achieved using `rbind` by referencing to the columns in the same way.